# Is it an optimistic approach?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In examples on an optimistic approach, @version (for example as parameter in procedures) is always in advance known.
Whether it is possible to receive @version in the procedure and on what it can affect.
Part of procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateTestTable2]
...
SELECT @version = [version]
FROM dbo.TestTable2
WHERE Id = @Id

BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE dbo.TestTable2
SET testName = @testName
WHERE Id = @Id AND [version] = @version
...
```

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi Whether is my approach the optimistic concurrency?

Comment: The first query in the SP is redundant.

Comment: Because in the second query you filter the table by ID and if it's unique (as it should be) you don't need any extra criteria.

Comment: The @version variable at me checks the version of a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "version" needs to come from the app and reflects the version of the record that has been selected for update. This information is then included as part of the update to ensure that one is updating the same version of the record that is being "viewed".

This is what you seem to be doing by supplying some information from outside (in this case @id). But, as Igor points out, there is nothing magic about a column called "version": you can drop your first select and leave the filter using @id.

But...what you are missing is a simultaneous update of the version/id field. You should do smoething like this:

```
update testtable2
set versioning_column += 1
where versioning_column = @versioning_column
```

that way, you are updating exactly the column you intend to, but at the same time are precluding anyone else from doing so by changing the version stamp.

Comment: Explain why it is impossible to receive the version of a row in the procedure?

Comment: @Alexander: because in the proc you have no way of knowing which version of the rows the app is seeing: they may already be stale if another process has updated them

Comment: `set versioning_column += 1` is enough, because the `WHERE` clause guarantees that the increment occurs only on correct app row version.

Comment: @davek replace set versioning_column = += 1 on set versioning_column += 1 I couldn't

Comment: @Alexander: sorry, my mistake - I have now corrected it (one "=" too many!). That assumes your versioning_column is of the appropriate type (int, bigint etc.)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to implement optimistic concurrency is to calculate a hash value when read data and then recalculate this value against the table before saving new data: if the hash value is different then the table was modified between the read and write operations.

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP(name VARCHAR(10), age TINYINT);
INSERT #TMP VALUES ('Ann', 10);
INSERT #TMP VALUES ('Ann', 10);
INSERT #TMP VALUES ('Ann', 20);
INSERT #TMP VALUES ('Beth', 10);
SELECT *, CHECKSUM(*) AS [hashvalue] FROM #TMP

-- name       age  hashvalue
-- ---------- ---- -----------
-- Ann        10   940063178
-- Ann        10   940063178
-- Ann        20   940063188
-- Beth       10   1206720504
```